# Preciso 'ler' o valor de uma variável que é local declarada em uma função, por em escopo de outra função, em script Python

Tags: python-3.x

Tenho um código que é muito semelhante ao seguinte

```
def um():
   x = 'abc'
   print(x)

def dois():
   y = 'bcd'+ 'x'
   print(y)
```

Acontece que, como `x` é local em função `um`, a função `dois` não consegue ler o `x`, retornando um erro que informa 'x não foi declarado'.

Answer (score 0):

Na função `um` está pedindo para imprimir o valor `x`,
o correto seria retornar esse valor. Já na função `dois`, a variável `y` recebe a concatenação de duas strings: `'bcd'` e `x`.

Acredito que a intenção seja ter acesso a variável `x` da função `um`.

E mais uma vez está imprimindo a variável em questão ao invés de retorná-la.

```
def um():
x = 'abc'
return x


def dois():
    y = 'bcd' + um()
    return y


print(dois())
```